# Why is it that I have to initialize the class and tk.Tk?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I'm just starting to get into object oriented programming. So I know that 'class App(tk.Tk)' makes tk.Tk the parent. If the class App is the basically the same as Tk here, why do I have to initialize App and tk.Tk separately?

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)


window = App()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: @sj95126 This was just an example, suppose I was going to do some special initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you don't. If `App.__init__` isn't defined, then the attribute lookup resolves to the `__init__` method of the parent (`tk.Tk`).

But since you *did* define `App.__init__`, the only way `tk.Tk.__init__` is called is if you call it explicitly. You should do so, to ensure that the object is appropriately initialized as an instance (via subclassing) of `tk.Tk`. Once that is done, you can proceed with your `App`-specific initialization.